# Highlight valid form element

Tags: forms

I'm using clientside validation module. It highlights only errors. How to display for example a green mark beside **valid** form elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Clientside Validation module adds classes 'valid' and 'error' to all form elements. You could use the class 'valid' to add the green mark simply with some css.